# Connect my organisation's SQL database to Power BI Report?

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

I am trying to connect my Power BI Report to my organization's SQL database. I just want to know that if it will assist me in providing business reports to the business on time. Currently we are doing extraction from database via FTP and putting it into Excel and cleaning the data and then formatting it to the user's needs. You can imagine the how tiresome this can will be.

Comment: This would be a good question for your organization, your work group, and your direct management. Here it is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

*I just want to know that if it will assist me in providing business reports to the business on time ?*

Answer is yes.

To get better outcome you need to do research on their logics, requirements, how visualization present, KPI etc..... Once you finalize those things you can start working on implementations.

Note: Try to identify visualizations that display stakeholder's requirements. Because powerbi dashboard only for the upper management level, They need to get business decisions only for looking at graphs.

They can export data via excel sheet, powerpoint slide or pdf for their need, so you need to format those excel sheets also with the implementations.

Comment: @rolandkayver -  If this is what you are looking you can mark this as answer